# Uploading an image to S3 bucket corrupts the image

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, .net-core, .net-6.0

I am facing an issue when I try to open the image downloaded from the s3 bucket.

[image]

This is how it looks.

Code I am using:

FE: Angular

Service code :

```
        saveFiles(request: FileObject): Observable<FileObject[]> {
        const formData = new FormData();
    
        if (request.file) 
    
        formData.append("file", request.file);
    
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(request)) {
    
          if (key !== "file") 
             formData.append(key, value as string);
    
        }
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/files/${request.tradeInId}`;
    
        return this.http.post<FileObject[]>(url, formData);
       }
```

Model FileObject:

```
  export interface FileObject {
  description: string;
  type: string;
  key: string;
  createdDate: Date;
  createdBy: string;

  // Only for ui
  file: File;
}
```

BE I am using Dot Net core:

```
     private async Task<string> UploadFile(IFormFile file, string prefix, CancellationToken 
      cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] fileBytes = new Byte[file.Length];
                file.OpenReadStream().Read(fileBytes, 0, 
                 Int32.Parse(file.Length.ToString()));

                var fullPath = $"{prefix}/{file.FileName}";

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);

                    var request = new PutObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = _bucketName,
                        Key = fullPath,
                        InputStream = stream,
                        Headers =
                        {
                            ContentDisposition = "attachment;", 
                            ContentEncoding = "base64"
                        },
                        ContentType = file.ContentType
                    };

                    await _client.PutObjectAsync(request, cancellationToken);
                }

                return fullPath;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("UploadAttachmentFileAsync-exception" + e.StackTrace);
                throw new Exception($"{e.Message}: 
                {Constants.MSG_FILE_STORAGE_ACCESS_FAILED}");
            }
        }
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here when I am uploading an image to S3 the image is getting corrupted and not getting opened correctly. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you confirm its not corrupted before the s3 upload? Looks like you upload the file onto a server before uploading to s3 correct? Is the file in a good state on the server before s3 upload?

Comment: Can you open the image on the browser directly?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil The image is not corrupted. When I locally run my API and make a request from the Postman to upload the image it gets uploaded and then I download the image then it gets downloaded properly. 

Like you asked Is the image file good when it is in server, for this I have no Idea how to check this that image is good on server or not. Can you help me to know how I can check it on server?

Comment: @benlux63 Yes I can open the image directly on the browser and it is in the corrupted state.

Comment: In this line "return this.http.post<FileObject[]>(url, formData);" are you posting the image to a server that you control? Like is this an Amazon EC2 instance then from there you're posting to s3 from the ec2?

Comment: Yes Posting to EC2 and then from there making BE API call to upload the image to the S3 bucket

Comment: This issue is solved. I forgot to add the binarymediatype in the API gateway for the Image/jpeg or any type of file